# Catenating string in for loop

Tags: luatex, document-classes

I'm extending my document class with possibility of handling multiple authors. I've chosen API to be like:

```latex
\author[1]{Foo}
\author[2]{Bar}
```

And implemented it like:

```latex
% def part
\def\author[#1]#2{\expandafter\def\csname @author#1 \endcsname{#2}}

% maketitle part
\foreach \n in {1,...,4}
    {
        \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
            {
                \ifcsname @author\n \endcsname
                \sffamily
                \Large
                \@nameuse{@author\n}
                \par
                \fi
            }
        \end{varwidth}
```

The problem is with

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle=\@title,
        pdfauthor=\authors,
        pdfsubject=\@abstract,
        pdfkeywords=\@keywords
    }
}
```

because I have no idea how can I implement catenation. When tried to go with same as in maketitle part, `lualatex` crashes.

**How can I make list of authors?** Do you have any suggestion of improvements (tikz foreach alternative, API/def change, etc)?

Comment: `\def\author[#1]#2{\expandafter\def\csname @author#1 \endcsname{#2}}` makes the `[..]` argument non-optional, which goes against all latex syntax, you should make it optional or use `{}` not `[]`.

Comment: you can just make your list as you go along so start with `\def\authors{\@gobble}` and then `\def\author[#1]#2{\expandafter\def\csname @author#1 \endcsname{#2}\g@addto@macro\authors{, #2}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - How about \protected@edef?

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes

Comment: I've noticed that foreach can not be used in the AtBeginDocument, so switched to \loop \repeat

Answer (score 1):

You can make two lists.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth,pgffor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{authors}
\let\authorlist\@empty
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{authors}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname @author\arabic{authors}\endcsname{#1}%
  \xdef\authorlist{%
    \ifx\authorlist\@empty
      \unexpanded{#1}%
    \else
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\authorlist}, \unexpanded{#1}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\@author}{%
  \foreach\n in{1,...,\value{authors}}{%
    \begin{varwidth}[t]{\columnwidth}
    \sffamily\Large\@nameuse{@author\n}
    \end{varwidth}\quad
  }%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{
    pdftitle=\@title,
    pdfauthor=\authorlist,
%    pdfsubject=\@abstract,
%    pdfkeywords=\@keywords
  }%
}

\title{Title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\author{W. Riter}
\author{Ç. Édille}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]